# Is there any web site to give Patent Classification by entering the Classification code?

Tags: search, patent-services, us-class

I want a web site to search for a patent classification by entering the classification code .

For example , if I enter G02 then I have to get optics ,  G02C5/14 ->  Side members like that.. Is any site available like that . (it may be either US classification codes or International classification codes )

I found some site who indexed classification , but don't provide a search system..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the USPTO provides a classification structure that you can navigate through here ==> http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/selectnumwithtitle.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could do a google search which would look like:

> [g02c 5/14 site:www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification](https://www.google.lt/search?q=g02c%205%2F14%20site%3Awww.uspto.gov%2Fweb%2Fpatents%2Fclassification&oq=g02c%205%2F14%20site%3Awww.uspto.gov%2Fweb%2Fpatents%2Fclassification&aqs=chrome..69i57.685j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

and there is a USPTO page similar to one linked in previous answer: http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/ but it doesn't have a search system.